# how to instantiate panel each time

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

in order to have a panel with dynamic content according to the content of active tab, I'm bootsrapping angularJs, invoking a controller then setting contents by services that get data from an online API.
How can I configure the panel to instantiate every time it's gonna open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox doesn't instantiate the panel each time you click of action button, unlike the Chrome and Safari. but a show message can be sent transmitted between main script and content script to trigger functions when popup opens